# How to change the datagridView Header color

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Now the datagridView Header Background color is showing in Gray.  I want to change to differenct
color.

I Changed the background color in `ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle`, but nothing changed.

How to do this.

Comment: dublicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921497/setting-gridview-header-color

Comment: @Soner,  I am using Windows Based Application

Comment: @Gopal, then you should give dataGridView and not gridview simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In datagridView you can change the Header color by using [DataGridViewCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx#Y1708), see the following code

```
       ' Set the selection background color for all the cells.
    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White
    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black

    ' Set RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor so that its default
    ' value won't override DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor.
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty

    ' Set the background color for all rows and for alternating rows. 
    ' The value for alternating rows overrides the value for all rows. 
    dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray

    ' Set the row and column header styles.
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black
```

EDIT:

Using the DataGridViewCellStyle, your header color will changes but a seperator for columns in the header section will not appear. So, heres a overrided event of OnPaint Event Handler have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067942/data-grid-view-header-grid-color)

Answer (score 29):

Set the property `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` to `False`, then change the `ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle` background color to the color that you desire. You will be able to see the changes in the designer itself.

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you are trying to set the color (back or fore)color or other properties of the individual column's header (not all at once) use

```
datagridview.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = color.cyan
datagridview.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.(ForeColor or Font or Alignment etc) = whatever
```

where e.ColumnIndex was taken from the EventArgs of your Event, but you can alter accordingly.

Comment: Make sure you have set yourGrid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false, or the suggested settings will have no effect